# Drag And Drop between asp.net Listboxes

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, listbox

i have two asp.net list boxes. i want to move the items from one list box to anther using drag and dropping. i tried to use j Query but dint seem to work. i also changed my list box to HTML select but still the same . i tried to add buttons to do the same . my code is as follow . any help will be much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Setter, #Getter").sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
    $(document).ready(
   function () {
       $('#Selectone').click(
           function (e) {
               $('#Setter > option:selected').appendTo('#Getter');
               e.preventDefault();
           });

       $('#SelectAll').click(
       function (e) {
           $('#Setter > option').appendTo('#Getter');
           e.preventDefault();
       });

       $('#RemoveOne').click(
       function (e) {
           $('#Getter > option:selected').appendTo('#Setter');
           e.preventDefault();
       });

       $('#RemoveAll').click(
       function (e) {
           $('#Getter > option').appendTo('#Setter');
           e.preventDefault();
       });

   });
</script>
```

```
  <select id="Setter" runat ="server" datasourceid="LinqDataSource1" class="sortable"   multiple="true"  draggable="true" datatextfield="Section" datavaluefield="Section" dropzone="Getter" size="30" >  </select>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="WebApplication1.insentraDataContext" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="Section" Select="new (Section)" TableName="Sections">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
  <asp:Button ID="Selectone"  runat="server" Text=">" />
  <asp:Button ID="SelectAll"  runat="server" Text=">>" />
  <asp:Button ID="RemoveOne"  runat="server" Text="<" />
  <asp:Button ID="RemoveAll"  runat="server" Text="<<" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to take a different approach to achieve the drag and drop between the list boxes connected with the database. my solutions is as follow.
 instead of having an asp.net list box ,i created a listview with a ul

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ListView ID="Listview1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    Unallocated Sections
    <ul class="sortable" draggable="true" id="Setter" style="overflow: scroll; empty-cells: hide; height: 500px; width: 200px; border: solid  1px; background: #b6b6b6;">
        <li id="Li1" runat="server" draggable="true" style="user-select: element;">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" id-="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </li>

    </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li id="Li2" runat="server">
                        <%# Eval("Section")%>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </td>
        <td>Allocated Sections
             <ul class="sortable" draggable="true" id="Getter" style="overflow: scroll; height: 500px; width: 200px; border: solid  1px; background: #fff;">
                 <li style="color: red;"></li>
             </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and javascript as

```
$(function () {
        $("#Setter,#Getter").sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortable"
        }).selectable();
    });
```

you can choose different options according to you need but it does accomplish the drag and drop between the listboxes . for more options  refer http://jqueryui.com/sortable/